# How can I connect to a remote socket server with "namespace" and parameters?

Tags: python, sockets, tornado

I need to connect from python client to a tornado server using an url like `ws://localhost:8006/user?id=666`.

I have tried something like this:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect('ws://localhost:8006/user?id=666')
print s.recv(1024)
s.close
```

...and got the following error:

```
TypeError: getsockaddrarg: AF_INET address must be tuple, not str
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not use a python websocket client library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't *connect* to a remote socket with a `namespace` and `parameters`.  You connect with a host and port.  Period.  Python's [socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#module-socket) module is a thin wrapper around native sockets.  It doesn't know anything about protocols like http, or ws.

You can connect to the host and port that your web socket uses.  Then you can send any parameters you like...but it's not going to understand them, unless you use the [websocket protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

Your best bet is to use a websocket client that someone else has written (see some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142705/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-python))

If you want to write it yourself, [here](http://popdevelop.com/2010/03/a-minimal-python-websocket-server/) is a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

You must convert string to tuple. Pratic example:

```
x = "(1,2,3)"
t = tuple(int(v) for v in re.findall("[0-9]+", x))
```