# Autobahn cannot import name error

Tags: python, autobahn

I have installed twisted and Autobahn websocket by using

```
pip install twisted
pip install autobahn
```

But when I import any of the factories from Autobahn, I get the cannot import name error.

```
    >>> from twisted.internet import reactor
    >>> from autobahn.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
    ImportError: cannot import name WebSocketClientFactory
```

Is there anything I am missing? 
Here's the pip freeze

```
Twisted==13.2.0
Twisted-Core==12.3.0
Twisted-Names==12.3.0
Twisted-Web==12.3.0
autobahn==0.7.4
websocket==0.2.1
websocket-client==0.13.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks as thoough `WebSocketClientFactory` is in [twisted sub-module](http://autobahn.ws/static/reference/python/websocketclient.html#autobahn.twisted.websocket.WebSocketClientFactory):

`from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory`

Comment: My code was using 0.6.5 earlier which was working fine. First thing I should have done is to look into my site-package to see if something has changed. Thanks!

Comment: The package has moved with 0.7.0 (since Autobahn|Python now supports both Twisted and asyncio). Please see: https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnPython#upgrading-from-autobahn--070