# How to connect to socket.io using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, socket.io

I want to connect to Socket.IO server using python. Is there a way to do it?

I have tried `websocket-client` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11105554/2469495).

```
ws = create_connection("ws://example.com:1000/socket.io/")
```

That code throws this exception

```
websocket._exceptions.WebSocketConnectionClosedException: Connection is already closed.
```

I feel like I am missing parameters because the JS client connection URL looks like this:

```
ws://example.com:1000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=CHARSANDNUMBERS
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use the url from the JS client, possibly without the sid:

```
ws = create_connection("ws://example.com:1000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket")
```

From my personal experience I didn't have that sid param, but just try to add it if it doesn't work without.

Comment: "Socket.IO is NOT a WebSocket implementation. Although Socket.IO indeed uses WebSocket for transport when possible, it adds additional metadata to each packet. That is why a WebSocket client will not be able to successfully connect to a Socket.IO server, and a Socket.IO client will not be able to connect to a plain WebSocket server either." ([source](https://socket.io/docs/v4/#what-socketio-is-not))

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this: [socketIO-client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/socketIO-client)

As an example,

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

socketIO = SocketIO('localhost', 8000)
```