# real time communication between python server and a python client(not a browser)

Tags: python, sockets

Back in the javascript world there is a library all the socket part called [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

the way it works is by send and receiving the data by and events.
for example: the server can send to the client an event called "msg_received" with the message itself as the data.

in python it seems to not be as asynchronous as its in javascript. its also not working with events but only with strings which is a bit diffrent than how i use to work with the sockets.

i.e `socket.send(<string>), socket.recv(<integer>)`

i would love if anyone could put some light the issue to explain to me how it works in python since i've searched all over the internet and couldn't find an answer.. or point me to a similar library like the one i mentioned above.

Comment: See this: [Is there a WebSocket client implemented for python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142705/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-python).

Comment: And for server, see [Tornado](http://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/).