# Send data from Python to node a server with socket (NodeJS,Socket.io)

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I trying to send sensor data (in python) from my raspberry pi3 to my local node server.

I found a module for python called [requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) to send data to a server.

Here I'm trying send the value 22 (later there will be sensor data) from my raspberry pi3 to my local node server with socket.io.The requests.get() works but the put commmand doesn't send the data.

Can you tell me where the mistake is ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#

import requests

r = requests.get('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080');

print(r)

r = requests.put('http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8080', data = {'rasp_param':'22'});
```

In my server.js I try to get the data but somehow nothing getting received

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express')
,   app = express()
,   server = require('http').createServer(app)
,   io = require('socket.io').listen(server)
,   conf = require('./config.json');

// Webserver
server.listen(conf.port);

app.configure(function(){

    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

// Websocket
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

    //Here I want get the data
    io.sockets.on('rasp_param', function (data){
        console.log(data);
    });

    });
});

// Server Details
console.log('Ther server runs on http://127.0.0.1:' + conf.port + '/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using HTTP PUT from Python, but you are listening with a websocket server on nodejs side.

**Either** have node listening for HTTP POST (I'd use POST rather than PUT):

```
app.post('/data', function (req, res) {    
    //do stuff with the data here
});
```

**Or** have a websocket client on python's side :

```
ws = yield from websockets.connect("ws://10.1.10.10")
ws.send(json.dumps({'param':'value'}))
```

A persistant websocket connection is probably the best choice.

Comment: hmm I see, thx :) Do you know how I can easily create a websocket for python 2.7.9 ?

Comment: sure check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142705/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-python